# Twitter search: how do I include spaces before and after search string? (hint: %20 doesn't work!)

Tags: http, encoding, twitter

I want to search tweets which contain a standalone string "$T", for instance:

```
$T is doing well today!
I can't wait to catch my flight with $T
If $t is down, I am happy
```

But I do not want results that include $T as part of a larger string, for instance

My mother said $ttttttt so I shut up
  Making money fa$t!!

For this, I tried 3 different search queries, with 2 of them encoding spaces before and after the string:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%24T
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=+%24T+
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%20%24T%20
```

But all of this doesn't help. What should be the correct query or do I just have to filter the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try quotation marks and/or plus signs in your search, like the [web based search interface does](https://search.twitter.com/search?q=%22+foo+%22)?

Comment: That's like the one thing I hadn't tried; which is stupid of me since I * always * use quotation marks, for instance when Googling...well, this solved it. Thanks!